# Second HTTP Get request to express server fails without error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, httprequest

I have a practice project using react, express, mongodb, and axios that is supposed to reach out to my localhost express server after the user stopped typing, get the results, and index them. This works on the initial request, but after making the initial request, parsing the data and displaying, I try to make a follow up request and it errors out on the `axios.get(url)`.

I have debugged both ends, and it seems to error out when I get to the `axios.get()`. I can step into this function, it gets through the binding, and then just stops. I have put in `catch()` statements for the entire get chain and I get no errors in return, and if I run debugging on the express end, it doesn't even get hit on the second request.

**Express server**

```
app.get('/api/search/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server
        await client.connect();
        // Establish and verify connection
        await client.db('funko').command({ ping: 1 });
    } finally {
        console.log('started exp');
        let query = req.query.q;
        query = query
            .split(' ')
            .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
            .join(' ');
        console.log('db req');
        const findResult = await client
            .db('funko')
            .collection('popems')
            .find({
                title: { $regex: '^' + query + '*' },
            })
            .toArray();
        console.log('finished req');
        if (findResult.length === 0) {
            res.send('No Results');
        } else {
            res.json(findResult);
        }

        await client.close().then(console.log('closed'));
        res.end();
        console.log('res ended');
    }
});
```

**Get Request**

```
const getPops = async (event) => {
        console.log('started pops');
        let url = new URL('http://localhost:5000/api/search/');
        url.searchParams.set('q', event.target.value);
        console.log('set params');
        //get data
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            console.log('making request');
            //set search results state object
            setSearchResults(
                res.data().then((e) => {
                    console.log('set results');

                    return setSearchResults([...e]);
                })
            );
        });
    };
```

Comment: You say "fails without error", but you don't have a `catch(err)` clause with logging to catch and log errors.  You just have `try/finally`, not `try/catch/finally`.   Then, inside your `finally` clause, you don't catch or log any errors in there.  Start by modifying your code to log every possible error.  Similarly, in your `axios.get()` call, you don't catch or log errors.   Whenever there's any mysterious problem, I always start by making sure I am logging ALL possible errors.

Comment: A couple small things that are wrong.  `await client.close().then(console.log('closed'));` should be `await client.close().then(() => console.log('closed'));` so the `console.log()` is only called when the promise actually resolves, not immediately.  And, you should NOT be calling `res.end()` at all here.  Both `res.send()` and `res.json()` already end the request.

Comment: Then, does `res.data()` really return a promise?  It seems to me in the axios doc that `res.data` is an object, not a function that you call.  If that's the case, then `res.data().then()` would not be correct.

Comment: The whole concept of wrapping your `client.connect()` in a `try/finally` and then assuming that the `.connect()` succeeded with the code in your `finally` clause is just fundamentally flawed.  The `finally` clause executes whether the `try` block succeeded or threw so you can't assume the `.connect()` succeeded in the `finally` clause.  This is just a wrong use of that structure.

Comment: Also, an API that sometimes returns text `"No Results"` and sometimes returns a JSON result is really difficult for a client to use.  You should always be returning JSON for request that doesn't have an error.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I have adjusted the await.close statement to be correct and I had the res.end in place because I just started guessing at how I could get it to work. However in regards to the Try, Catch block, I just pulled that from the MongoDB example but I will work on adjusting it. Finally, I originally had .catch() statements attached but they were not throwing any sort of error, and I've reattached them with the same results

Comment: You will not get any error. If you add a catch statement, you will. The you are specifically telling the computer to ignore any errors that pop up. ==edit== ahh I just saw your above comment